# Question based on percentages: How many mangoes did Murali have in the beginning?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Murali has a certain number of mangoes, $15\%$ of which are rotten. He gives $60\%$ of the remaining to his friend and is left with $102$ fresh mangoes.
>
> How many mangoes did he have in the beginning?

Suppose Murali has $x$ mangoes and $15\%$ are rotten. So the number of fresh  mangoes is $0.85x$.

He gave $60\%$ of the remaining to his friend means $\frac{60}{100}\times\frac{85}{100}\times x=0.51x$.

Remaining fresh mangoes is $0.49x$. So $0.49x=102$.

But this doesn't give me the right answer. Where am I making mistake?

Comment: What is the 'correct' answer (and the source of this)?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to subtract the amount of rotten mangoes. Assuming there are $x$ mangoes, we have $0.15x$ rotten mangoes and $0.85x$ fresh ones. Murali gives away $60\%$ of the fresh mangoes, leaving him with $0.85x - 0.6 (0.85x) = 0.34x = 102$ fresh mangoes. As such, the total number of mangoes equals:

$$x = \frac{102}{0.34} = 300$$